Embedding a lingusitic data which includes mathemtatical equations in LaTeX form
I need to embed a lingusitic data which includes mathemtatical equations in LaTeX form for a NLP process. I have a row data which includes data like
\[\n3 \times 2+4-5\n\]

Where do the brackets
I did think about dropping the LaTeX symbols like \  or $ then make the embedding first but on the base model I could not  find any significance.
The ai programs suggest me to embed the linguistic and LaTeX data separately but it also make me think that I could lose meaningful correlations. Since I am trying to make a semantic embedding. The sentences and questions have certain meanings which the equations are an important part of those meaning. Therefore I would like to know is there any way for to make that embedding as treating the data as a whole.

it isn't clear if there is any TeX question here at all?  surely mathematics in the text is just like having anything else such as foreign language words, you deal with them however you want to deal with them in your system, there isn't really any tex specific issue
